# Printing module response at HTTP request with Node.js, basic problem

Tags: node.js, http, github

I have never used node.js (only PHP) but found a node module, but I am already trying to figure this issue for 3 hours now.

I use this module: [Play Scraper](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper)

They run it with this code, which works great from SSH console

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
gplay.app({appId: 'com.google.android.apps.translate'})
.then(console.log, console.log);
```

However I want to run it as HTTP server and get responses printed as JSON there, that's my code:

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.write("hello!\n");
            
        var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
        gplay.app({appId: 'com.google.android.apps.translate'}).then(
            result => {
                res.write(result);
            }
        )
        
        res.write("bye!\n");
        res.end();
});

server.listen(8080);
console.log('server running on port 8080');
```

I only get the "hello" and "bye" nothing between. I realised the issue is probably because I want to get module response inside. If I play the gplay.app just before server.listen(8080) and go console.log it works great in SSH.

How to print the gplay.app response on the screen (JSON.stringify) and where is the issue now that it doesn't work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider several things about working with JavaScript. Everything you do which is IO is generally non blocking, unless specified. When using a callback or a `then` (called a Promise) the code will not wait for any callback before continuing to the next statement. JavaScript in recent years made this much easier to understand with async await syntax sugar.

The best way to fix you code is to implement this async await syntax:

```
const http = require('http');
// Best practice to import everything at the start
const gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.write("hello!\n");

        // the result will be "awaited" and then written into the response.
        res.write(await gplay.app({appId: 'com.google.android.apps.translate'});

        res.write("bye!\n");
        res.end();
});

server.listen(8080);
console.log('server running on port 8080');
```

However, to understand why your solution doesn't work let's step through your code

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
        // Write operations (to a buffer, which is what this response object is)
        // are not asynchronous. You do not need to wait for a response
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.write("hello!\n");
            
        var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
        // Calling ".then" means waiting for the result to complete and issuing
        // your given `res.write` once the response has been provided.
        gplay.app({appId: 'com.google.android.apps.translate'}).then(
            result => {
                // if we only write the next part of the response
                // once our result has been fetched, then the writes
                // will occur in the correct order
                res.write(result);
                res.write("bye!\n");
                // and your "end" will fire after your response has been written
                res.end();
            }
        )
});
```

Hope this helps you understand a bit better.